# Lighttpd config error

Tags: lighttpd

I have this config error:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/lighttpd restart
Stopping web server: lighttpd.
Starting web server: lighttpdDuplicate config variable in conditional 0 global: fastcgi.server
2011-09-25 19:12:13: (configfile.c.855) source: /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf line: 178 pos: 10 parser failed somehow near here: (EOL) 
 failed!
```

Here's my config file: http://pastebin.com/kzW1kCP5

May I know what went wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message, you have another `fastcgi.server` configuration directive somewhere. As it's not in the main configuration file, it's probably imported from another file. See what you can find in `/etc/lighttpd/conf-available` and `/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled`.

[Serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/) would maybe have been a better place for this question. As a matter of fact, there's a [question over there](https://serverfault.com/questions/112617/lighttpd-wont-restart-due-to-an-fastcgi-server-error) which is very similar to yours.